# Importing stopword dictionary to python

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

How can I import a specific stopword dictionary (excel sheet) into Python and run it additionally to the nltk stopword list? Currently my stopword section looks like this:

```
# filter out stop words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can import an excel sheet using the `pandas` library. This example assumes that your stopwords are located in the first column, one word per row. Afterwards, create the union of the `nltk` stopwords and your own stopwords:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
# check pandas docs for more info on usage of read_excel
custom_words = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', header=None, names=['mywords'])
# union of two sets
stop_words = stop_words | set(custom_words['mywords'])
words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
```